# Get a DateTime for one week ago

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the DateTime of one week ago to use it in a query. So I've done:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But for some reason this is not working right. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Um, why aren't you just doing it in the query?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`DateTime::sub()` returns a new DateTime object. It doesn't change the original object at all.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$newdate = $date->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
$date = $newdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OQj2Q2)

If you want to do this a little simpler:

```
$date = new DateTime('-1 week');
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/A4N5Ug)

Comment: Keep in mind that `$date->sub(...)` MODIFIES the original `$date` variable. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.sub.php).